# Not able to put ArrayList into Bundle in onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android

Is any way to put this into Bundle during `onSaveInstanceState`?

```
public static ArrayList<StringProArrayList> splnenoNa1 =
    new ArrayList<StringProArrayList>();
```

The method `putStringArrayList` don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're not passing it an `ArrayList<String>`. What you want to do it is implement `Parcelable` in your `StringProArrayList` class and use `putParcelableArrayList`.